# C enum as a type in a structure when using bit fields

Tags: c, bit-fields

It was my understanding that the type for the bit field declarator should be of some int type. In fact, here is the line from the C99 standard

> "A bit-ﬁeld shall have a type that is a qualiﬁed or unqualiﬁed version of _Bool, signed >int, unsigned int, or some other implementation-deﬁned type."

However, I came across some code today which shows an enum as the type, like this.

```
typedef enum
{
    a = 0,
    b = 1
}ENUM;

typedef struct
{
    ENUM id : 8;
}STRUCT;
```

Without comments or documentation, it's hard to tell the intent. Could anyone provide some insight?

Comment: Looks like they're forcing the `enum` to be 8 bits wide within the `struct`.

Comment: Hmm, okay that seems to make since. Must have had some really strict memory restrictions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a` and `b` are both of the `int` type, `signed int`. It has a length of **32 bit**, meaning 4 Byte.

But the enum `ENUM` does not need that much.

```
0000000000000000000000000000000 equals a
0000000000000000000000000000001 equals b
```

So the creator thought making the `ENUM` shorter than `int` with a `bitfield` of the length of **8 bit**, minimum length 1 Byte.

```
00000000 or 00000001
```

He could have taken the `char` type from the beginning with the length of 1 Byte though.

On some compilers you can activate a feature to ensure an enum can be smaller than int. Using the option --short-enums of GCC, makes it use the smallest type still fitting all the values.

---

Here is an example how you would save memory with a bitfield.
You see the `someBits` struct is smaller than `twoInts` struct.

```
#include "stdio.h"

struct oneInt {
  int x;
};

struct twoInts {
  int x;
  int y;
};

struct someBits {
  int x:2; // 2 Bits
  int y:6; // 6 Bits
};


int main (int argc, char** argv) {
  printf("type int = %lu Bytes\n", sizeof(int));
  printf("oneInt = %lu Bytes\n", sizeof(struct oneInt));
  printf("twoInts = %lu Bytes\n", sizeof(struct twoInts));
  printf("someBits = %lu Bytes\n", sizeof(struct someBits));
  return 0;
}
```

#### Output:

```
type int = 4 Bytes
oneInt = 4 Bytes
twoInts = 8 Bytes
someBits = 4 Bytes
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! I wasn't aware of the --short-enums option. That could be useful in the future.

Comment: Why is `someBits` 4 bytes. Shouldn't it be two bytes, one for each field?

Comment: @saga the bits in `someBits` are stored in an int type, hence the 4 bytes. If the fields were `char x:2` and `char y:6` the size would be 1 byte.